# Numerical analysis: getting back in time for a second derivative equation using Runge Kutta

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have a physical model:
\begin{align}
x''(t) &= a {\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}} x'(t) \\
y''(t) &= b {\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}} y'(t) + c \\
\end{align}
or written differently (with speed as $v_x$ and $v_y$):
\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial t} &=  a v v_x \\
\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial t} &=  b v v_y + c\\
v &=  {\sqrt{(v_x^2 + v_y^2)}}
\end{align}
I know a set of discrete points for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ from $t = 1$ to $t = 2$.

[image: x and y curve over time]

*This is the x and y curve over time from $t=0$ to $t=2$*

**QUESTION:**

I need a numerical analysis to "go back in time" and approximate $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ from t=0 to t=1. How can I do that?

One idea is to calculate multiple Runge kutta simulations for different x(0) and y(0) values and find which one "fits best" the discrete values after t=1 but I was wondering if there would be a better method.

I'm interested by the maths but it's a numerical analysis so ultimately, I'm looking for pseudo code to solve this problem.

Comment: why you are just inactive n waste others time

Comment: Explain the downgrade? Seriously?

Comment: You can also just integrate with a negative timestep: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011452/runge-kutta-fourth-order-with-negative-stepsize

Answer (score -1):

First, estimate the parameters $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ as well as you can.

Then set $u = -t$ and find the equations in terms of $u$ instead of $t.$

Then use your existing Runge-Kutta algorithm to integrate from
$u = -1$ to $u = 0.$