# Runge-Kutta fourth order with negative stepsize

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am solving an ODE using the Runge-Kutta method 4th order and the integration is backward i.e step size ($h$) is negative. All the references that I have seen consider the positive step size.

Is it ok to change $h$ to $-h$ in Runge-Kutta method or is there any change in sign in $K$ values?

Comment: No, if you do it consistently, then there should be no change. Also check your loop conditions, going backwards is not as intuitive as going forward.

Comment: You mean there is no change in equations and I can use -h instead of h. Can you give me any references.

Comment: I do not know where this is explicitly stated, Hairer-Norsett-Wanner is always a good reference to look into. If you have a procedure `y_next = rk4step(f,t,y,h)` that works correctly for positive `h`, then it works also correctly for negative `h`. Remember that the time step remains `t_next = t+h`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a procedure

```
y_next = rk4step(f,t,y,h)
```

that works correctly for positive `h`, then this same procedure also works correctly for negative `h`. Remember that the time step remains

```
t_next = t+h
```

The only problem that may arise is the control of the loop. If the sampling times are given as array, then the loop

```
 for k in range(1,len(t)):
      y[k] = rk4step(f,t[k-1],y[k-1], t[k]-t[k-1])
```

will work independent of the direction of the time sample points.

If the loop control is based on the end time, then `while t < tf` works for positive `h`, for negative `h` one has to switch the sign or include `h` as in `while 0<(tf-t)*h`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My only worry is the signs within K's . Is h needs to be multiplied to all K's or just at the end while calculating y_next.

Comment: As I said, you use the same sequence of computations as for positive $h$, the RK4 step does not depend on the sign of $h$. If you use `k.. = h*f(..)` or shift the multiplication with `h` to the combinations of the `k`, `y_next = y + h*(k...)` does not matter, as long as you use only one variant of these.