# Runge Kutta fourth order stepsize

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am solving an ODE using the Runge-Kutta method 4th order and the integration is backward i.e step size (h) is negative. All the references that I have seen consider the positive step size.

Is it ok to change h to -h in Runge-Kutta method or is there any change in sign in K values?

Comment: It's about mathematics.

Comment: Then I think you'll be better off asking this on that site I linked. It's off topic here (we try to focus simply on the applications of the software and let the math.stackexchange people have the pure math).

Comment: Question already exists as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3011452/115115